# Calculating correlations between response and certain explanatory variables

Tags: r

I want to create a single column that lets me know the correlations for my dependent variable with all of the explanatory variables that I am interested in (all these columns and many more are stored in a data.frame d).  By doing cor(d) I can get all the correlations and by doing cor(d$Var1, d$Var2) I can get a single number, but I want to figure out how to get only the Var1 column from the matrix returned by cor(d), with my being able to select the explanatory variables I want included.

Answer (score 4):

The cor function can actually do this as well.
Suppose we have:

```
d=data.frame(dependentVar = c(1,2,3),var1=c(-1,-2,-3),var2=c(9,0,5),junk=c(-2,-3,5))
```

Then this will do the trick:

```
cor(d[,"dependentVar"], d[,c("var1","var2")])
     var1       var2
[1,]   -1 -0.4435328
```

It's less efficient (I guess), but you can also do this:

```
cor(d)["dependentVar", c("var1","var2")]
```

which computes the full correlation matrix, and then pulls out the subset you want.

Answer (score 4):

@DavidR is correct, though R also supports correlation between the columns of X and columns of Y as:

```
cor(X, Y)
```

See `?cor` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
M <- round(cor(College[,-1]),2)

library('corrplot') #package corrplot
```

We can use circle, square, eclipse also instead of number if we want images instead of direct numbers

```
corrplot(M, method = "number") #plot matrix
```

[Corelation matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCxfh.png)